# jmx error while using cassandra driver in multiple wars deployed in same jvm

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I have app1.war and app2.war deployed in the same tomcat jvm. Both apps have their own context xmls - app1.xml and app2.xml. 
Both applications contain datastax driver dependancies to connect to Cassandra. They run well when they are deployed separately. But when both are deployed in the same jvm, I am seeing below JMX exceptions in logs:

```
[DEBUG] [TokenId=] [2015-07-29 20:54:35.177] [DefaultListableBeanFactory] - [Eagerly caching bean 'cluster' to allow for resolving potential circular references]
[DEBUG] [TokenId=] [2015-07-29 20:54:35.191] [DefaultListableBeanFactory] - [Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'cluster']
[DEBUG] [TokenId=] [2015-07-29 20:54:35.199] [SystemProperties] - [com.datastax.driver.NEW_NODE_DELAY_SECONDS is undefined, using default value 1]
[DEBUG] [TokenId=] [2015-07-29 20:54:35.199] [SystemProperties] - [com.datastax.driver.NON_BLOCKING_EXECUTOR_SIZE is undefined, using default value 16]
[DEBUG] [TokenId=] [2015-07-29 20:54:35.205] [SystemProperties] - [com.datastax.driver.NOTIF_LOCK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS is undefined, using default value 60]
[WARN ] [TokenId=] [2015-07-29 20:54:35.217] [FrameCompressor] - [Cannot find Snappy class, you should make sure the Snappy library is in the classpath if you intend to use it. Snappy compression
will not be available for the protocol.]
[WARN ] [TokenId=] [2015-07-29 20:54:35.219] [FrameCompressor] - [Cannot find LZ4 class, you should make sure the LZ4 library is in the classpath if you intend to use it. LZ4 compression will not
be available for the protocol.]
[DEBUG] [TokenId=] [2015-07-29 20:54:35.356] [Cluster] - [Starting new cluster with contact points [xxxxx1.com/10.63.162.182:9042, xxxx2.com/10.63.162.177:9042, xxxx3.com/10.63.162.183:9042]]
[DEBUG] [TokenId=] [2015-07-29 20:54:35.556] [JmxReporter] - [Unable to register gauge]
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: cluster1-metrics:name=open-connections
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
        at com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter$JmxListener.onGaugeAdded(JmxReporter.java:494) [metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry.notifyListenerOfAddedMetric(MetricRegistry.java:344) [metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry.addListener(MetricRegistry.java:187) [metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter.start(JmxReporter.java:697) [metrics-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Metrics.<init>(Metrics.java:77) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar:?]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.<init>(Cluster.java:1204) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar:?]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.<init>(Cluster.java:1144) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar:?]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:121) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar:?]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:108) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar:?]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:177) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar:?]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1109) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar:?]
```

The application works functionally. I am just concerned on why I am seeing this error and how to avoid this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you indicated, this won't cause any issues other than not registering one of the Cluster's metrics MBeans.  To prevent this message/problem, you can give your Cluster instances unique names, maybe tied to the name of your application itself.

```java
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().withClusterName("myapplication")
            .build();
```

This will prefix your mbean name with 'myapplication-1'.

Otherwise you can disable JMX metrics alltogether using [withoutJMXReporting](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withoutJMXReporting()) or [withoutMetrics](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withoutMetrics()) to disable metrics reporting.

Comment: You beat me to it Andy... Normally the driver handles it on its own with a counter (cluster1, cluster2...), but in that case that fails because the counter is stored in a static field and each application has its own classloader. The MBeans server is unique though, hence the collision.

Comment: Great point on the separate classloader.  I was trying to understand why that counter wasn't incrementing but makes sense if each webapp has its its own loader.

Comment: If Flink (which i'm not familiar with) uses a separate classloader wherever it is creating Cluster instances, than you are right, it needs to provide a unique cluster name, or you could simply disable Jmx metrics.